# XSLT 1.0 get distinct with multiple child nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an xml with multiple nodes and subnodes. And I need the distinct nodes.
I've found a lot of examples, but they are for single child nodes, not when I want to check on multiple child nodes. They either don't work for me, or I only get 1 subnode every time. Not the full Row group.

```
<Rowsets>
  <Rowset>
    <Row>
       <alpha>1111</alpha>
       <bravo>2222</bravo>
       <charlie>3333</charlie>
    </Row>
    <Row>
       <alpha>165165</alpha>
       <bravo>2165165</bravo>
       <charlie>654165</charlie>
    </Row>
    <Row>
       <alpha>1111</alpha>
       <bravo>2222</bravo>
       <charlie>3333</charlie>
    </Row>
  </Rowset>
</Rowsets>
```

So I need an output with distinct Row nodes.
As you can see, the first and last Row node are the same.
How do I get an output with only 2 Row nodes, since the 3rd is only a double.

Something like this:

```
<Rowsets>
  <Rowset>
    <Row>
       <alpha>1111</alpha>
       <bravo>2222</bravo>
       <charlie>3333</charlie>
    </Row>
    <Row>
       <alpha>165165</alpha>
       <bravo>2165165</bravo>
       <charlie>654165</charlie>
    </Row>
  </Rowset>
</Rowsets>
```

Rowsets node is not necessary. I just need the unique Row nodes.

Currently I'm trying to find it in this direction:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Rowsets/Rowset/Row[alpha = following::Rowsets/Rowset/Row/alpha and bravo = following::Rowsets/Rowset/Row/bravo and charlie = following::Rowsets/Rowset/Row/charlie]"/>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). Make your key:

```
<xsl:key name="row" match="Row" use="concat(alpha, '|', bravo, '|', charlie)" />
```

and output only Rows that satisfy:

```
Row[count(. | key('row', concat(alpha, '|', bravo, '|', charlie))[1]) = 1]
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Row[. = preceding-sibling::Row]"/>
```

Comment: seemingly the OP could have multiple rowsets and want to disctinct acrocss them, also this is just saying thhe text is the same, ie <a>12</a><b>3</b> == <a>1</a><b>23</b> by this metric

Comment: Well, that's simple and very effective. Thanks a lot. It works like a charm.

Comment: @tolanj what do you mean exactly? I tried it, and it removed the rows that had a duplicate. Are there any special cases I should be aware of? It should be distinct as a combination of all the child nodes.

Comment: make a second copy of you duplicate row, remove the final 5 of alpha, add it to the front of bravo, is now unique, wont appear in the output

Comment: This is saying 'is the value of the text in row 1 == value of the text in row2'

Comment: I understand what you mean now. This is luckily not possible in my case, since all the child nodes are quite unique. But how would you fix this then?

Comment: This is not a good method for two reasons: (1) it can easily produce false positives (as was already explained); and (2) it is **very inefficient"*. Use Muenchian grouping instead.